# How do View.setX(), View.setRotation(), and View.getWidth() work relative to one another?

Tags: android, android-layout

In Android, I am creating a custom layout. It contains a view that I need to position, rotate, and then measure precisely.

If I have a 10x10px view that I move 10px right, 10px down, and then rotate 45 degrees, how wide will the view measure itself and where precisely will it be positioned?

```
view.setX(10)
view.setY(10)
view.setRotation(45)
view.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec)
```

Will it still report 10px as its width, or will it take its rotation into account? Are the x and y coordinates aligned with the rotated corner, or do the remain fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rotation`, `translationX`, `translationY`, `translationZ`, `scaleX`, `scaleY` - those are **Canvas** attributes. It means that you tell Android where to draw view **after** it has been measured and laid out relative to view's `x` and `y` position. Those attributes do not affect default measuring routine (unless you override `onMeasure` in your custom view and take those into account, but I highly don't recommend doing that). So changing any of those attributes will not affect view measurments

`x`, `y` - are **layout** attributes. It means that parent of this view decides where to position it relative to itself, so if you set those values before `onLayout` is called - these values will be overridden by parent. If you override `x` and `y` **after** `onLayout` - you can change position of this view within its parent. But if you go after this effect - I would rather use `translationX` and `translationY` attributes since the very next `onLayout` call will reset `x` and `y` again.

But to answer your original question - yes, it will report `10px` as its width. None of the mentioned above attributes will actually affect reported width or height of the view

**EDIT** As Dave pointed out, my original statement regarding `x` and `y` are being overridden during layout is not really correct. Setting `x` and `y` attributes will internally set `translationX` and `translationY`, so updating these attributes is effectively the same as updating translation

Comment: According the documentation, `setX()` and `setTranslationX()` do the same thing, differing only in being absolute vs relative: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setX(float)

Comment: it will **visually** do the same as `translation`, but as I mentioned in my answer there is a conceptual difference between those two. Changing `x` and `y` will take effect only till the next `onLayout` call. During layout process parent will recalculate `x` and `y`, so you need to update them again. `translationX` and `translationY` will remain the same throughout layout

Comment: Hmm. I have to disagree. I just checked the source of View.java and `setX()` calls `setTranlationX()` directly: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#L11802

Comment: Interesting. I guess you are right. I think I was confused by `getLeft` vs `getX`. Learning something new every day